# Colisión de dlls en la carpeta bin

Tags: genexus

Estoy trabajando con Gx 17 generando c# y necesito incluir algunas dlls. El problema inicial es que una de ellas es Newtonsoft.json, en una versión diferente a la que trae Gx. Quiero colocar todas las dlls en una carpeta dentro del bin. Es posible? Como le indico a Gx que tiene que buscar las dlls ahi?

Answer (score 0):

Buen día.
Todas las ddl que copia a la webapp las copia desde la instalación de Genexus por ejemplo: "C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17", podés sustituir la ddl desde ahí.

La otra solución (desprolija) es crear un .bat que copie con el comando xcopy de una ruta a la webapp y agregar él .bat en Build/ Build Events y agregarlo en el Post-Build event command line para que ejecute el bat cada vez que finalice un build.